# DAL Web Services C#

Tags: c#, web-services

I have an application in layers in C#, and I need that when you go enter the DAL, check if connected by VPN or not. This in order to connect to a web service when you do not have the VPN and make the query execution, but if you do all the VPN connected locally by the DAL dll, and the connection to the database you can perform with the local server name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is multiple option

1. if VPN connection is always required for DAL to connect to database then always on init of DAL try opening a SQL Connection and check if it works good or else VPN is not present.
2. VPN is ppp connection so you can check using this code if any PPP connection is active and try opening SQL connection and see if it works

   ```
       if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
       {
           NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
           foreach (NetworkInterface Interface in interfaces)
           {
               if (Interface.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
               {
                   if ((Interface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ppp) && (Interface.NetworkInterfaceType != NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback))
                   {
                       IPv4InterfaceStatistics statistics = Interface.GetIPv4Statistics();
                       MessageBox.Show(Interface.Name + " " + Interface.NetworkInterfaceType.ToString() + " " + Interface.Description);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       MessageBox.Show("VPN Connection is lost!");
                   }

               }
           }
       }
   ```